# Scrolling with laptop pointing stick doesn't work in NetBeans

Tags: thinkpad, scrolling, trackpoint

I have a [Lenovo ThinkPad X201s](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/notebooks/thinkpad/x-series/x201s) laptop. I'm using the laptop's [TrackPoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick) (the red pointing stick which functions as a mouse) in order to scroll. Scrolling using the TrackPoint usually works for me, with one exception: [The NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/). NetBeans is the only application in which I can't scroll using the TrackPoint.
Scrolling in NetBeans does work when using a mouse.

How can I make scrolling in NetBeans work when using the TrackPoint?

**More Info:**

- My OS is Windows 7 Professional.
- I'm using NetBeans 7.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I found this thread on the Netbeans forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-52264.html) which seems to indicate it that manually adding an exception to the Synaptics app may solve it (and at least one other person who thinks it might be a Java problem as well). [Here's](http://www.syaoran.net/blog/2010/01/how-to-enable-thinkpad-trackpoint-scrolling/) a good version of what appears to be the same directions for adding the exception. (You don't mention what OS you're using so I assume it's the out-of-the-box Windows).

If nothing else, it's certainly a [known problem](http://www.google.com/search?q=netbeans%20trackpoint).

Comment: My OS is Windows 7. Just added it to my question.